# @PrePersist not invoked for referenced objects?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a recursive data structure like this:

```
@Entity
class Node {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Reference
    private List<Node> children;

    ...

    @PrePersist
    void populateSequentialId() {
        // query data store for highest id and increment, then set the id field
    }
}
```

Then I populate a tree of Node objects, all without ids set. The depth varies, but usually it is about 3 levels deep.

When I call `save()` on an object without children, it works. The id is generated and set, and object is saved. That means the @PrePerist was invoked on that entity as expected.

But for entities that are in the Referenced list @PrePersist is never invoked, and the `save` call fails due to a null `@Id` field.

Is this a bug in Morphia or I'm having the wrong expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to persist every document on its own.

So if A references B:

1. Persist B
2. Persist A, so you have B's `_id` for the reference

Otherwise the operation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle annotations on a class are only used when persisting objects of that type.  When you have `@Reference` annotations on fields, those referenced objects are only used to store the key value in the referencing document.  The referenced object is not persisted or processed in any way.  You'll need to save that referenced object manually and then the `@PrePersist` will be applied.